# SPFileCollection.Add REST endpoint

Tags: office-365, rest, designer-workflow

I am working on a project where I need to copy a document from one site to another site in Office365. I want to achieve this using SP designer workflows. I learn that I can use `SPFileCollection.Add` method to achieve this. However I couldn't figure out the correct REST URL so that I can use it in call HTTP WebService step in Workflow. Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

REST Endpoint URL to add a file to library

```
<appWebUrl>/_api/sp.appcontextsite(@target)/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('<serverRelativeUrlToFolder>')/files" + "/add(overwrite=true, url='<fileName>')?@target='<hostWebUrl>'
```

But you may need to use JQuery with REST, refer the below link for more details.

Reference: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn769086.aspx)

SPD is not going to help in this case, your choices are limited. As there is no direct option, you must handle it by a trigger of an even which is going to be a client side event such as page load, button click, mouse over, etc.

If you are going to fo it in a custom page use appropriate function calls by injecting the JS into it.

If it is a List forms, you may use presaveaction() method.

Comment: Hello Nagarajan, Thank you for your reply. Is there any way we can use jQuery with REST in sharepoint 2013 designer workflows?

Comment: No direct option to have jquery and SPD workflow. So handle it in JS itself.